# Can this be SQL injected?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm wondering if my code is actually protected from SQL injection. My sites have been injected before and I never really understood how to prevent it. Here is my code for inserting a comment:

```
if ($_POST['comment']) {
    $comment = strip_tags(nl2br(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment'])));
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (comment, authorid)
    VALUES ('$comment', '$uid')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo '<div style="width: 98%; max-width: 98%; border: 1px solid white; background-color: green; color: white; vertical-align: text-top; text-align: center;">Your comment was added to the wall!</div><br>';
}
```

Comment: I build them for fun. I'm only a high school student

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string and PDO ?!?

Comment: yes, it is possible. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: this is the kitchen sink approach, your jurt adding every function you can find in the manual with out understanding any of them

Comment: You'd be better understanding the differences between `strip_tags()`, `nl2br()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` and what they actually do, and when to use them...... and then switching to using prepared statements/bind variables and only using those functions when appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can probably be injected: you don't appear to be protecting your `$uid` variable. Also, stacking `nl2br` and `strip_tags` *after* escaping is a bad idea - you want to leave `mysql_real_escape_string` as the *last* operation to avoid any filter interaction effects.

More generally, you should use **prepared statements**, not string interpolation, to build SQL queries. It's simpler, more efficient, more secure and requires less code. You can create a prepared statement using [`$conn->prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and execute it with arbitrary arguments:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (comment, authorid) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($comment, $uid));
```

No escaping required.

Comment: Prepared statements have the added benefit that a prepared statement is *not allowed* to contain more than one SQL statement, which is necessary for most SQL injection attacks to succeed.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax: Actually, SQL injection is perfectly feasible with only a single SQL statement in many contexts using *nested queries* - sometimes all you need is to read sensitive data out of the database.

Comment: Ok. So what about updating? How would I go about that?

Comment: You can use `prepare` with any SQL query, including `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, etc.